# How to select several hardcoded SQL rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

If you execute this query

```
SELECT 'test-a1' AS name1, 'test-a2' AS name2
```

the result will be a one row-selection with two columns having these values:

```
test-a1, test-a2
```

How can I modify the above query to have a selection with several rows, e.g.

```
test-a1, test-a2
test-b1, test-b2
test-c1, test-c2
```

I know how to do this with UNION but I feel that there exists a more simple way to do it.

PS. Sorry for such a basic question, it is very hard to google it.

Comment: Do you have a table to select from?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use union? Are there a large number of values?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

UNION ALL is the best bet. It's faster than UNION and you will have mutually exclusive rows.

Comment: Here is the Oracle answer that helped me the best (note there is a solution for strings rather than numbers as well, just look for my comment):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353969/how-can-i-select-from-list-of-values-in-oracle/10355365#10355365

Comment: @HLGEM the opposite, UNION ALL generates duplicate rows while UNION generates mutually exclusive rows.

Answer (score 88):

Values keyword can be used as below.

```
select * from 
(values ('test-a1', 'test-a2'), ('test-b1', 'test-b2'), ('test-c1', 'test-c2')) x(col1, col2)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why UNION ALL answer is preferred over this one?

Comment: This code snippet can’t run in MuSQL 5.6.25. Is it a new feature in 5.7?

Comment: This example worked fine in MS SQL Server for me, but not in Oracle.

Comment: Returns syntax error on 10.6.4-MariaDB-1:10.6.4+maria~focal-log

Comment: This works in Postgres! The Postgres docs have it written as `(SELECT * FROM (VALUES (...), (...), ....) AS t(col_name1, ...)` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html

Comment: This was super easy to use in excel to generate the insert lines with a `(A2, B2),` per row

Answer (score 60):

The following will work for SQL:

```
SELECT 'test-a1' AS name1, 'test-a2' AS name2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'test-b1', 'test-b2'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'test-c1', 'test-c2'
```

Answer (score 8):

Extending the [answer of @openshac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6346038/283787) for oracle, as the below mentioned code works for oracle:

```
SELECT 'test-a1' AS name1, 'test-a2' AS name2 from dual 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'test-b1', 'test-b2' from dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'test-c1', 'test-c2' from dual
```

Answer (score 5):

The following code work for me in MSSQL environment:

```
SELECT Name1,Name2 FROM(VALUES  ('test-a1', 'test-a2'),
                                   ('test-b1', 'test-b2'),
                                   ('test-c1', 'test-c2'))AS Test(Name1,Name2)
```

Output:

```
Name1   Name2
------- -------
test-a1 test-a2
test-b1 test-b2
test-c1 test-c2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a temp table, fill it up with your results and then select from it

```
create table #tmpAAA (name1 varchar(10), name2 varchar(10))
insert into #tmpAAA (name1, name2) 
values ('test_a', 'test_b'),
       ('test_c', 'test_d'),
       ('test_e', 'test_f'),
       ('test_g', 'test_h'),
       ('test_i', 'test_j');
select * from #tmpAAA;
```

This will return

```
name1   name2
==================
test_a  test_b
test_c  test_d
test_e  test_f
test_g  test_h
test_i  test_j
```

Answer (score 4):

As of MySQL 8.0.19, it is possible to do

```
SELECT
    column_0 AS name1,
    column_1 AS name2
FROM
    (VALUES
        ROW('test-a1','test-a2'),
        ROW('test-b1','test-b2'),
        ROW('test-c1','test-c2')
    ) AS hardcodedNames
```

Which returns

```
name1   name2
==================
test-a1 test-a2
test-b1 test-b2
test-c1 test-c2
```

A note on column names

> The columns of the table output from VALUES have the implicitly named columns column_0, column_1, column_2, and so on, always beginning with 0.

Documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html.

Answer (score 2):

I'd love to hear is anyone has a better solution.  In the past I've used this:

```
Select top 3 'Hardcode'
from tableWithLotsOfRows
```

Would you mind switching abc, with 123?

```
select top 3 
    'test-A'+convert(varchar, row_number() over (order by PrimaryKey)),
    'test-B'+convert(varchar, row_number() over (order by PrimaryKey))
from tableWithLotsOfRows
```

that should return something like:

```
TestA1, Test-B1
TestA2, Test-B2
TestA3, Test-B3
```

Comment: It's a MySQL question, so there are no ranking functions. But nice idea!

Comment: That sucks.  In t-sql i abuse the hell out of row_number().

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you could use [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) like this:

```
SELECT * from 
    (SELECT 2006 AS year UNION
     SELECT 2007 AS year UNION
     SELECT 2008 AS year UNION
    ) AS years
```

Comment: Don't need the final UNION

Answer (score 0):

With Mysql
[image]

code:

```
SELECT
    column_0 AS date,
    column_1 AS value
FROM
    (VALUES
        ROW('2023-01-01', 3434.33),
        ROW('2023-01-02', 5455.73),
        ROW('2023-01-03', 3434.53),
        ROW('2023-01-04', 3434.53),
        ROW('2023-01-05', 3434.53),
        ROW('2023-01-06', 3434.53),
        ROW('2023-01-07', 3434.53),
        ROW('2023-01-08', 3424.53)
    ) AS data
```