# To display multiple row into single & single row into multiple row?

Tags: sql, oracle

Need query to display single row to multiple row

ex:

A,B,C,D,E,f

change to

A

B

C

D

E

F

query to display multiple row to single row

ex:

A

B

C

D

E

F

change to

A,B,C,D,E,F

Comment: Traditionally that is a presentation layer issue, and having comma separated values in a database is an anti-pattern/code-smell.  Relational-Database design patterns are for normalised data, not comma separated lists.  Do you have a use-case that shows why you need to de-nomralise your data structures?  Perhaps we can point you at a different pattern that does not require that.

Comment: try the wm_concat function

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> with t as (
  2  select 'A,B,C,D,E,F' x from dual
  3  )
  4  select substr(x,(rownum-1)*2+1,1) from t
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(x,',')+1
  6  /

S                                                                               
-                                                                               
A                                                                               
B                                                                               
C                                                                               
D                                                                               
E 
F     

SQL> with t as (
  2  select 'A,B,C,D,E,F' x from dual
  3  )
  4  select listagg(s,',') within group (order by s) str
  5  from (
  6  select substr(x,(rownum-1)*2+1,1) s from t
  7  connect by level <= regexp_count(x,',')+1
  8  )
  9  /

STR                                                                             
---------------
A,B,C,D,E,F
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma/string to table: [How can I select from list of values in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353969/how-can-i-select-from-list-of-values-in-oracle)

```
 select column_value from 
   table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'));

SELECT trim(regexp_substr('Err1, Err2, Err3', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) str_2_tab
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count('Err1, Err2, Err3', '[^,]+')
/
```

Table to comma/string:

```
 WM_CONCAT() in 10g as jle mentioned or LISTAGG() in 11g.
```