# SQL How to only show fields from a list of numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, oraclereports

I have a table of items, each with an item ID(int). I want to only display items with item ID's based on a string. For example I want to display items "12, 1005, 2". This string is different every time. How would I do this?

Comment: So does the string contain comma separated ints and you want to find all records with those ID's?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: if it's passed in as a string, you might need to either parse out into a table or use dynamic sql

Comment: I should've mentioned, it's for Oracle Reports builder. The string is a User Parameter.

Comment: This is a common problem and question (stackoverflow has many related questions).  Look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353969/how-can-i-select-from-list-of-values-in-oracle.  I particularly like Justin Cave's approach (which reminds me of a Tom Kyte approach).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, you can use [IN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions013.htm#SQLRF52169):

```
select from item i where i.id in (12,1005,2)
```

Comment: How would I use the string though? If I have a `string a = "12,1005,2"` how would i use that in an sql query?

Comment: An unelegant approach (from a performance perspective) could be '%,'||to_char(i.id)||',%' like ','||'12,1005,2'||','

Comment: I don't know whats the problem you're trying to solve, but i think it's better to treat the string in you application. Can you use Execute Immediate? You can concat the sql -> "select from item i where i.id in (" with your string, then use execute immediate to query.

Answer (score 0):

is your parameter is always consist of 3 numbers or it may be different in runtime??
if it's fixed you can use substr and instr to cut

Comment: I believe it can be different in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider an approach documented by Justin Cave with the question, [How can I select from list of values in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353969/how-can-i-select-from-list-of-values-in-oracle).  Tom Kyte documents a similar approach (without regexpressions) on his Ask Tom site.

Since you are in an Oracle Apps environment using Oracle Reports, I just provide an example using the items table:

```
with x as
  ( select '12, 1005, 2' str from dual
  )
select *
from inv.mtl_system_items_b item
where item.organization_id =
  &org_id
and item.inventory_item_id in
  (select to_number(regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+',1,level)) element
  from x
    connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(str,'[^,]+')) + 1
  )
```

Procedurally in Oracle reports, you could create a function as a program unit that performs this parsing of this comma separated value parameter using similar logic (again, see Justin Cave's parse list function (answer associated with the question I refer to above).