# Substring in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a column that has several items in which I need to count the times it is called, my column table looks something like this:

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VTxx.png)

```
Id_TR               Triggered
--------------      ------------------
A1_6547             R1:23;R2:0;R4:9000
A2_1235             R2:0;R2:100;R3:-100
A3_5436             R1:23;R2:100;R4:9000
A4_1245             R2:0;R5:150
```

And I would like the result to be like this:

[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBhCG.png)

```
Triggered          Count(1)
---------------    --------
R1:23               2
R2:0                3
R2:100              2
R3:-100             1
R4:9000             2
R5:150              1
```

I've tried to do some substring, but cant seem to find how to solve this problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please replace the images with text (use ctrl-K to keep the format)

Comment: this is a regex type parse - and please tell the table designer to never design like this again..

Comment: Yeah I know it's being a headache to get the data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is X3 times faster than the CONNECT BY solution

performance: 15K records per second

```
with        cte (token,suffix)
            as 
            (
                select      substr(triggered||';',1,instr(triggered,';')-1)     as token
                           ,substr(triggered||';',instr(triggered,';')+1)       as suffix

                from        t

                union all

                select      substr(suffix,1,instr(suffix,';')-1)     as token
                           ,substr(suffix,instr(suffix,';')+1)       as suffix

                from        cte

                where       suffix is not null

            )

 select     token,count(*)
 from       cte
 group by   token
 ;
```

Comment: Works really nice! And it sends me the results in seconds, I'm evaluating the output data, but everything seems to work just fine! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is just for learning purposes.
Check my other solutions.

performance: 1K records per second

```
select      x.triggered
           ,count(*)

from        t
           ,xmltable 
            (
                '/r/x'
                passing xmltype('<r><x>' || replace(triggered,';', '</x><x>') || '</x></r>')
                columns triggered varchar(100) path '.'
            ) x

 group by   x.triggered
 ;
```

Comment: I'm trying out this option and so far so good, just validating actual data on the table.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fair solution.

performance: 5K records per second

```
select      triggered
           ,count(*)            as cnt 

from       (select      id_tr
                       ,regexp_substr(triggered,'[^;]+',1,level) as triggered

            from        t

            connect by      id_tr  = prior id_tr
                        and level <= regexp_count(triggered,';')+1
                        and prior sys_guid() is not null
            ) t

group by    triggered
;
```

Comment: Check this out.

Comment: is there any reason to use sys_guid() ?

Comment: @TymurGubayev - It prevents `ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data`

Answer (score 1):

```
with x as (
   select listagg(Triggered, ';') within group (order by Id_TR) str from table
)
select regexp_substr(str,'[^;]+',1,level) element, count(*)
  from x
  connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(str,'[^;]+')) + 1
  group by regexp_substr(str,'[^;]+',1,level);
```

First concatenate all values of `triggered` into one list using `listagg` then parse it and do `group by`.

Another methods of parsing list you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353969/how-can-i-select-from-list-of-values-in-oracle) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677070/split-function-in-oracle-to-comma-separated-values-with-automatic-sequence)

Comment: No reason to concatenate everything, just to de-concatenate later. Much more efficient to split each string separately.

Comment: Yes! When I concatenate it sends me an error that says ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long.

Comment: Looks like I need to change the data type to CLOB, since Varchar2 is very limited. I've been reading about using xmlagg, going to give it a try...

Comment: @Kacper The results are fine when my data set is small, but when I work with over 4000 rows it send me the ORA-01498