# How to make dual table with many rows in one col?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

**I tried to do so, but it returns me in columns not rows**

```
SELECT 386 ,417,420,421,422,423 ... from dual
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select from list of values in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353969/how-can-i-select-from-list-of-values-in-oracle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select column_value col1 from
table(sys.odcinumberlist((386) ,(417),(420),(421),(422),(423)))
```

Answer (score 1):

use `union all`

```
SELECT 386 from dual
union all
SELECT 417 from dual
union all
SELECT 420 from dual
union all
SELECT 386 from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` as a work around to get the desired output.

`SELECT 386 from dual 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 417 from dual 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 420 from dual
 ...`