# Select list as column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, union-all

I would like to append a few rows to an already existing table (15 rows to be precise). What is the quickest way to do this?

This works, but it seems redundant.

```sql
select person_id from people_table
union all
select '0010' as person_id from dual
union all
select '0019' as person_id from dual
union all
select '0085' as person_id from dual
```

I was wondering if there's a solution along the lines of:

```sql
select person_id from people_table
union all
select ('0010','0019','0085') as person_id from dual
```

Please note that I want to preserve the leading zeros for each element in my list. [This post is almost what I'm looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353969/how-can-i-select-from-list-of-values-in-oracle), but it converts each element to integers and drops the leading zeros.

Comment: "Concatenate" is a technical word, with a different meaning from the way you are using it. In a technical field like computing, using language imprecisely, like you are, causes a lot of problems.

Comment: Concatenating by rows is very common in tons of data frame libraries (python's `pandas.concat` for example). I didn't want to use `join` because that has a whole other meaning in SQL.

And what do you even mean by "technical word". Can you think of something more ambiguous to say?

Comment: Right. What you do want to do in your problem is to "union" (or "union all") a few rows to an already existing rowset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I select from list of values in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353969/how-can-i-select-from-list-of-values-in-oracle)

Comment: @PonderStibbons Almost! That syntax seems very convenient, but it converts each entry in my list to numeric values and gets rid of the leading zeros.

Comment: @ArturoSbr Second answer applies to varchars. And all answers posted here are covered there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a system-provided collection type; you select from it using the `TABLE` operator (even that is no longer necessary since Oracle 12, as I demonstrate below). Note that the column name is `COLUMN_NAME` - that is the name Oracle chose when they created the system-provided type.

Let's create a small table for testing:

```
create table people_table (person_id varchar2(10), person_name varchar2(10));

insert into people_table (person_id, person_name) values ('2003', 'Maria');
insert into people_table (person_id, person_name) values ('2005', 'Peter');
```

Then, here is how you can do what you wanted:

```
select person_id from people_table
union all
select column_value from sys.odcivarchar2list('1000', '1001', '1002')
;

PERSON_ID
---------
2005
2003
1000
1001
1002
```

Do a Google search for `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` (and similar `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST`) if you are not familiar with it; it's quite useful.

Comment: Perhaps worth adding, any scalar collection type will do, including ones you create yourself or others already present in the system: `select * from all_coll_types where coll_type = 'TABLE' and elem_type_name = 'VARCHAR2'`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the hiearchy query as follows:

```
select person_id from people_table
union all
select regexp_substr('0010,0019,0085','[^,]+',1,level) 
  from dual
connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace('0010,0019,0085', '[^,]+'))  + 1 ;
```

Comment: Awesome, this works.

Could you explain what the parameters `'[^,]+', 1, level` do?

Comment: This may work, but note that the OP doesn't have a comma-separated input, he does have several atomic inputs. Your solution assumes he will list-aggregate them first.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query using regular expression,

```
select person_id from people_table
union all
select distinct  trim(regexp_substr(('0010,0019,0085'),'[^,]+', 1, level) ) as person_id
 from dual
 connect by regexp_substr(('0010,0019,0085'), '[^,]+', 1, level)
 order by level;
```

Comment: This may work, but note that the OP doesn't have a comma-separated input, he does have several atomic inputs. Your solution assumes he will list-aggregate them first.