# In Oracle SQL how to make select to return all rows whose ID is in a list?

Tags: sql, oracle

Using the `HR.employees` table as an example. Suppose I want to check information for employee 205, 206 and 207. Note that 207 is not in the table. This is the query I will run:

```
select * from HR.employees
where employee_id in ('205', '206', '207');
```

This is the results I get:

```
+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------+------------+--------+----------------+------------+---------------+
| EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |  EMAIL   | PHONE_NUMBER | HIRE_DATE |   JOB_ID   | SALARY | COMMISSION_PCT | MANAGER_ID | DEPARTMENT_ID |
+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------+------------+--------+----------------+------------+---------------+
|         205 | Shelley    | Higgins   | SHIGGINS | 515.123.8080 | 02-06-07  | AC_MGR     |  12008 |                |        101 |           110 |
|         206 | William    | Gietz     | WGIETZ   | 515.123.8181 | 02-06-07  | AC_ACCOUNT |   8300 |                |        205 |           110 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------+------------+--------+----------------+------------+---------------+
```

Despite 207 is not in the table, I still want to see 207 in the query return. All the text columns except employee id can be null, while the numerical columns are all 0. Like this:

```
+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------+------------+--------+----------------+------------+---------------+
| EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |  EMAIL   | PHONE_NUMBER | HIRE_DATE |   JOB_ID   | SALARY | COMMISSION_PCT | MANAGER_ID | DEPARTMENT_ID |
+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------+------------+--------+----------------+------------+---------------+
|         205 | Shelley    | Higgins   | SHIGGINS | 515.123.8080 | 02-06-07  | AC_MGR     |  12008 |                |        101 |           110 |
|         206 | William    | Gietz     | WGIETZ   | 515.123.8181 | 02-06-07  | AC_ACCOUNT |   8300 |                |        205 |           110 |
|         207 | Null       | Null      | 0        | Null         | Null      | Null       |      0 |              0 |         0  |             0 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------+------------+--------+----------------+------------+---------------+
```

How do I modify the query to achieve this?

Comment: Construct a hard-coded list of the values, then left join from that to your table. Here's an SO question about constructing the list. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345635/how-to-select-several-hardcoded-sql-rows

Comment: What are you trying to do? This just _feels_ wrong

Comment: @Kevin I need to compare two tables entry by entry. One table is in an Excel spreadsheet, while the other table is in database. The Excel spreadsheet has a fixed list of entities that I need to check. And it can contain more entities than what the query would return. Currently I can't copy a whole column from the query because I have to skip entries that are in Excel but not in the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to unioning together lots of IDs to check is to use a collection and treat it as a table expression, then left-join from that:

```
select t.column_value as employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, -- e.email, ...
  case when e.employee_id is null then 0 else e.salary end as salary,
  case when e.employee_id is null then 0 else e.commission_pct end as commission_pct
  -- , ...
from table(sys.odcinumberlist(205, 206, 207)) t
left join employees e on e.employee_id = t.column_value;

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                     SALARY COMMISSION_PCT
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- ---------- --------------
        205 Shelley              Higgins                        12000               
        206 William              Gietz                           8300               
        207                                                         0              0
```

You could use `nvl()` or `coalesce()` for the number columns, but that would set the `commission_pct` to zero for all real employees (who don't have one set). Using a case expression to identify non-matched rows lets you be more selective.

If necessary the collection could be passed in from an application, for example by converting an array, as a bind variable and much more easily than constructing the union on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `left join`, but you need a source for the ids you are looking for.  A derived table can be used:

```
select *
from (select 205 as employee_id from dual union all
      select 206 as employee_id from dual union all
      select 207 as employee_id from dual
     ) i left join
     HR.employees e
     using (employee_id);
```

This returns `NULL` values for the unmatched columns.  If you actually want a different value, you'll need to list out the columns.

Note that with the `using` clause, you can use `select *` and not get a duplicate `employee_id` in the result.

Comment: This won't really do what he wants as he will get null values for everything, instead of the default 0's for number fields.  He'd have to throw in a bunch of NVLs as well. You also need another union all at the end of the select 206 line

Answer (score 0):

Make a temporary variable or table that contains a list of the IDs you want to see. Select that variable, then the fields from the table, where id is in your temporary list.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to put the employee ids you want to see in the output in a table, say empIdTable and then do a left join with it.

```
select * from 
empIdTable I
LEFT JOIN employees E
on I.employee_id = E.employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be one way to do it:

```
select *
from HR.employees e
right join (
    select '205' employee_id from dual

    union all

    select '206' employee_id from dual

    union all

    select '207' employee_id from dual
) lt
on lt.employee_id = e.employee_id;
```

But this will be a bad idea if you have a lot of `employee_id`'s to check.

Comment: What is the point of the with t (select * from hr.employees) instead of just joining on hr.employees?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was just doing some tests of my own that's why I left it like that.